# Matrix A has eigenvalue $λ$ , Prove the eigenvalues of Matrix $(A+kI)$ is (λ + k)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> The matrix A has an eigenvalue $λ$ with corresponding eigenvector $e$.
>
> *Prove* that the matrix $(A + kI)$, where $k$ is a real constant and I is the identity matrix, has an eigenvalue $(λ + k)$

---

My Attempt:

$$(A + kI)e$$

$$= Ae + kIe = λe + ke = (λ + k)e$$

---

Yes I proved it, but I'm not happy with the proof and I don't think its a good proof. Reasons:

- I started out assuming this : $(A + kI)e$ , But It should be :

$$(A + kI)x$$

> And I don't know how to prove this way ^^^

Even though it might seem obvious to some of you (not for me) and after the proof it's obvious that $x=e$ , it wasn't right for me  to start my proof with it (since its not mentioned that x=e.

So How do I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you don't want is an "ad hoc" proof that doesn't make it clear where it comes from, is that it?

Then you could use the characteristic polynomial of A :

Let P be that polynomial :

P(X) = det(A - X*I) = det( A+k*I - (X+k)*I) = Q(X+k) , where Q is the characteristic polynomial of A+k*I

P(X) = 0 <=> X= λ, with λ an eigenvalue of A.

An eigenvalue λ' of A+k*I is defined as such : λ' eigenvalue of A+k*I <=> Q(λ') =0

But : Q(λ')=0 = P(λ' -k ) <=> λ'-k is an eigenvalue of A, since it verifies P(λ'-k) = 0

So you can say that it exists a λ, eigenvalue of A, such as : λ' -k = λ

So you get the result you were looking for, and you can even affirm that the set of eigenvalues of A+k*I is {λ +k, λ eigenvalue of A} since the proof is made with equivalency all along the way

Comment: Ummmm, give me a moment as Im trying to think what's happening here

Comment: I can provide you with more details, tell me

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: (upvoted!) Yes It is :))))

Comment: Characteristic polynomial can be a very powerful tool sometimes, this is only the premises :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start with $x$, then this means you want to find $x$ such that 
$$(A+kI)x = (\lambda + k)x$$
since $(A+kI)x = Ax + kx$, this reduces to find $x$ such that 
$$Ax + kx = (\lambda + k)x$$
i.e. $$Ax = \lambda x$$
then one will naturally think of taking $x = e$

Comment: Of course, this way one has to check again that the steps used for *finding* a suitable $x$ were equivalences. So in the end the *proof* of the claim is exactly as in the OP: One pulls $e$ out of the tophat and verifies that it is an eigenvector of the desired eigenvalue.

Comment: See here you started of equating (A+kI) Infact has a eigenvalue $$(\lambda +k)$ . What you have proved is "Show that (A+kI) has a eigenvector e, where $(k+ \lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of (A+kI)"?

Comment: Oh you mean first prove e is the eigenvector (what you have done) and then  it's no longer an assumption so , after what you did I can write my answer?

Comment: @XNova I want to find $x$ such that $x$ is an eigenvector with the eigenvalue $\lambda + k$, then I show this reduces to find $x$ such that $Ax = \lambda x$

Comment: @LiuGang Got itttt :)

Answer (score 1):

The point is you need to find a non zero vector $v$ such that  $(A+KI) v = \beta v$ and $ \beta $ is said to be the eigenvalue of $(A+KI)$. 
So consider $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$ then : 
$(A+KI) x = Ax + Kx = \lambda x + Kx = (\lambda + K) x $ . 
This implies that  $\lambda+ K $ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: we know that $x$ is non zero since it is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$.

Comment: You used $Ax= \lambda x$ ?

Comment: yes I have found a non zero vector. I chose  that to be the eigenctor of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$.

Comment: You did exactly the same proof as I did, except that you used x instead of e, but even the question has stated $Ae=\lambda e$

Comment: @Nova please refer to the definition of eigenvector and eigenvalue