# What are the eigenvalues of the matrix $A+2I$ when $A$ is given?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Question:** What are the eigenvalues of the matrix $A+2I$ if
$A =\begin{bmatrix}3 & 2\\5 & 0\end{bmatrix}$?

**My attempted solution:** I'm actually not quite sure how I should approach this problem. I know that that the augumenting matrix $A+2I$ is $\begin{bmatrix}5 & 2\\5 & 2\end{bmatrix}$, but other than that I'm not quite sure how to go about solving this problem. I'd be much appreciated if someone could explain this to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The simple example [here should](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/977974/635046

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c_1,...,c_n$  be eigenvalues of $A$ then

$t=c_i$ $\Rightarrow$ $\det(A-tI)=0$

$\det((A+2I)-tI)=\begin{vmatrix} 5-t & 2 \\ 5 & 2-t \end{vmatrix}=(t-5)(t-2)-10=t(t-7)$

roots of determinants are $7$ and $0$ so our eigenvalues are $0$ and $7$.

Comment: i fixed it thanks :)

Comment: Thank you!${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $Av=\lambda v$ for some $v\ne0$. Therefore
$$
(A+2I)v=Av+2v=\lambda v+2v=(\lambda+2)v
$$
and so $\lambda+2$ is an eigenvalue of $A+2I$.

The converse is also true: if $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A+2I$, then $\mu-2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ (similar proof).

Thus you find *all* the eigenvalues of $A+2I$ by adding $2$ to the eigenvalues of $A$. Note that $A$ can be of *any* order.

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $x^2-3x-10=(x+2)(x-5)$, so the eigenvalues are $-2$ and $5$. The eigenvalues of $A+2I$ are $0$ and $7$.